# How I can change images in docx file with python

Tags: python, docx, zip, python-docx

I need change all images in docx file. How can i do it?

Now i download images with changing but i want change in docx

```
import zipfile

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw #Подключим необходимые библиотеки.


def change_img(path):
    image = Image.open(path)  # Открываем изображение.
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)  # Создаем инструмент для рисования.
    pix = image.load()  # Выгружаем значения пикселей.
    for i in range(image.size[0]):
        for j in range(image.size[1]):
            a = []
            for k in range(3):
                a.append(pix[i, j][k])
            a = sum(a) // 3
            draw.point((i, j), (a, a, a))
    return image


archive = zipfile.ZipFile('document.docx')
for file in archive.filelist:
    if file.filename.startswith('word/media/'):
        change_img(str(archive.extract(file)))
```

Comment: What did a search on `"python-docx replace image"` turn up?

Comment: @scanny I couldn't even get an image with python-docx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.